# Erro ao se conectar com MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Eu peguei um exemplo da internet para me conectar com o MySQL

```
private static final String USUARIO = "root";
private static final String SENHA = "123456";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/aulas";
private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

public static Connection abrir() throws Exception
{   
    Class.forName(DRIVER);

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, SENHA);

    System.out.println("Conectado");

    return conn;
}
```

E acontece esse erro

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at Default.Main.abrir(Main.java:52)
at Default.Main.<init>(Main.java:64)
at Default.Main.main(Main.java:36)
```

Como eu posso arrumar isso ??

EDIT

```
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.zip"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Descompacte este .zip para ficar .jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque o driver do mysql não está no seu classpath. Para resolver, você pode baixá-lo manual através do link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
Ou então pode adicionar a dependência no maven se você usa o mesmo adicionando ao seu arquivo pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Olá, eu já inclui o driver e continua acontecendo o erro(imagem na pergunta).

Comment: Confira se o driver aparece no classpath.

Comment: Eu já consegui arrumar, Obrigado.

Comment: Qual era o problema?

Comment: @LucasCarezia se minha resposta foi convincente, marque a como Aceitação de Resposta por favor.

Comment: Eu apenas me esqueci de colocar o Connector.jar dentro da pasta JAVA

Comment: Entendi, que bom que seu problema foi resolvido. Obrigado :)